# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '????' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

Ao realizar UPDATE em uma coluna VARCHAR(4) utilizando um valor inteiro na clausula  SET.

```
UPDATE TESTE SET ID = 9250 WHERE ID = 1234
```

É retornado o erro abaixo:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '????' to data type int.

Entretanto o erro ocorre apenas em um dos servidores com SQL Server 2008 R2 o outro servidor que possui a versão idêntica não ocorre o erro, porem não consegui identificar se tem algum parâmetro diferente de um servidor para o outro. Alguém já viu este tipo de erro???

Comment: Se a coluna e string vc deve atribuir um valor string a ela, neste caso vc esta tetando atribuir um valor inteiro, ao invés de `9250` tente `'9250'`.

Comment: Dener, se eu realizar este processo funciona, porem eu desejo saber porque uma instancia aceita eu inserir o valor inteiro e a outra não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode reproduzir o problema assim.

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE
(
    ID varchar(4) NOT NULL
);
GO
INSERT INTO TESTE (ID)
    VALUES ('1234'), ('4567');
GO
UPDATE TESTE
    SET ID = 9250
    WHERE ID = 1234;
GO
TRUNCATE TABLE TESTE;
GO
INSERT INTO TESTE (ID)
    VALUES ('1234'), ('4567'), ('ABCD');
GO
UPDATE TESTE
    SET ID = 9250
    WHERE ID = 1234;
GO
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABCD' to data type int.

O sistema converte os valores na coluna `ID` para `int` para fazer o `WHERE`. Falha se um valor não pode ser convertido.

Então é bem provavel que no servidor que mostra o error tem um valor não numérico na coluna ID.